# Finite dimensional unitary representations of the discrete Heisenberg group

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, unitary-representations, heisenberg-groups

Let $H(\mathbb{Z})$ be the discrete Heisenberg group. What are the finite dimensional irreducible unitary representations of $H(\mathbb{Z})$? Do they all arise from the coordinate-wise quotient map to a Heisenberg group over a finite field $H(\mathbb{Z}) \to H(\mathbb{F}_p)$?

I am not sure if I can apply a Stone-Von Neumann like result, since $H(\mathbb{Z})$ is over the integers, and not over a field.

Comment: No, but they all factor through a virtually abelian quotient. Indeed the Zariski closure of the image is a nilpotent compact Lie group, hence virtually abelian. Conversely every f.g. virtually abelian group has a faithful finite-dim unitary representation, so we can't expect more.

Comment: The irreducible representations of $H(\mathbb{Z})$ are listed in [Davidson, C*-algebras by Example. Theorem VII.5.1] or in [Boca, Rotation C*-Algebras and Almost Mathieu Operators. Chapter 1].